# I get ENOMEM error when I run a raspistill or a raspivid:

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi

I get the following error when I run either `raspistill` or `raspivid`:

```
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detetected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

I have reinstalled the camera strap several times.  The led light also is on on the camera.

Comment: Have you checked `gpu_mem` is adequate in `/boot/config.txt` https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/memory.md

Comment: Did you run `sudo Raspivid-config` and enable the camera in there and reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Below solved it for me

```
sudo raspi-config
-> 5 Interfacing Options
-> Camera
-> Yes
-> Reboot
```

Comment: Any reasoning for downvotes? Above menuconfig did solve my camera issue and I think I found this ticket by googling ENOMEM and raspistill.